# select2 alignment not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-select2

select2-3.5.2 was working fine. but as soon as i upgrade to 4.0.3 it is suddenly appearing on left side of the page. I am using jquery-UI, hoping these two will play well together.

**float:right; is having no impact on select2-4.0.3**

```
    <div style="position:absolute; top:0px; left:0px; width:100%" class="ui-widget infobar-wrapper">
        <div name="ibar1" id="ibar1" class="ui-widget-header infobar">
            <select name="themes" id="themes" style="float:right;">  <!--margin-top:-3px;-->
              <option></option>
              <option value="black-tie">black-tie</option>
              <option value="trontastic">trontastic</option>
              <option value="ui-darkness">ui-darkness</option>
              <option value="ui-lightness">ui-lightness</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
```

as i do this in JS:

```
$("#themes").select2({dropdownAutoWidth:true,placeholder:'Change theme'});
```

css:

```
.infobar {
    height:27px;
    font-weight:bold;
    overflow:hidden;
    border:0px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Appear to, yet it also appears the `float` should be moved to another item.

**CSS**

```
.infobar {
  height: 27px;
  font-weight: bold;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 0px;
}

.infobar .select2-container {
  float: right;
}
```

Working Example: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/Lq7q5xxj/

Comment: thank you. I did not know there is something like .select2-container...